# Stop Mavericks opening Safari in whichever screen I happen to be in?

Tags: finder, safari, macos

I have a hotkey on my mouse that opens Safari, and since Mavericks, it'll open it in whichever monitor currently has focus (or the non-greyed-out menu bar).

I want it to always open in the same spot on one display, like it did with Mountain Lion. Is there a way I can have that happen?

Comment: This is highly doubtful to me, but you might want to search your Apple Script library to see if anything is related to multiple displays. Maybe also the Automator builtins. There is at least 90% chance that the answer is no I guess.

Comment: Apple opens a door, and they close a window. Or move it. Nice.